# How to implement a while loop into this code

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to code this area calulator but I'm having a hard time understanding how to implement a while loop, any help would be appreciated. I have tried looking into loops but I'm not quite understanding how to write them even after watching some YouTube videos.

```
def calculate_square_area(side:float):
    return side * side

def calculate_rectangele_area(length:float, width:float):
    return length * width

def calculate_circle_area(radius:float):
    pi = 3.14
    return pi * radius **2

def calculate_rhombus_area(p: float, q: float):
    return p*q/2


print("""
---------------
Area Calculator
---------------
""")

selection = input("""\t 'S' - Square
\t 'R'- Rectangle
\t 'C'- Circle
\t 'H'- Rhombus
""")

def calculate_area(selection):
    area = 0
    if selection == "S":
        side =input("Enter The Side:")
        area = calculate_square_area(float(side))
    elif selection == "R":
        length = input ("Enter The Length:")
        width = input ("Enter The Width:")
        area = calculate_rectangele_area(float(length), float(width))
    elif selection == "C":
        radius = input ("Enter The Radius:")
        area = calculate_circle_area(float(radius))
    elif selection == "H":
        p = input("Enter P:")
        q = input ("Enter Q:")
        area = calculate_rhombus_area(float(p), float(q))
           
    else:
        print ("Invalid selection")
        
    return area
        
def get_shape_name(tag):
    shape = "Unkown"
    if tag =="S":
        shape = "Square"
    elif tag == "R":
        shape ="Rectangle"
    elif tag == "C":
        shape = "Circle"
    elif tag == "H":
        shape = "Rhombus"
    return shape  

area = calculate_area(selection)

print(f"The area of the {get_shape_name(selection)} is {area}")
```

Comment: Why can you not implement a while loop by writing `while <condition>:` and then some indented code after that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Like this? The while loop makes the area calculator run repeatedly until you enter `Q`, so you can calculate the area of multiple shapes.

```
def calculate_square_area(side:float):
    return side * side

def calculate_rectangele_area(length:float, width:float):
    return length * width

def calculate_circle_area(radius:float):
    pi = 3.14
    return pi * radius **2

def calculate_rhombus_area(p: float, q: float):
    return p*q/2

def calculate_area(selection):
    area = 0
    if selection.upper() == "S":
        side = input("Enter The Side:")
        area = calculate_square_area(float(side))
    elif selection.upper() == "R":
        length = input ("Enter The Length:")
        width = input ("Enter The Width:")
        area = calculate_rectangele_area(float(length), float(width))
    elif selection.upper() == "C":
        radius = input ("Enter The Radius:")
        area = calculate_circle_area(float(radius))
    elif selection.upper() == "H":
        p = input("Enter P:")
        q = input ("Enter Q:")
        area = calculate_rhombus_area(float(p), float(q))

    else:
        print ("Invalid selection")

    return area

def get_shape_name(tag):
    shape = "Unkown"
    if tag.upper() =="S":
        shape = "Square"
    elif tag.upper() == "R":
        shape ="Rectangle"
    elif tag.upper() == "C":
        shape = "Circle"
    elif tag.upper() == "H":
        shape = "Rhombus"
    return shape  


print("""
---------------
Area Calculator
---------------
""")

while True:
  selection = input("""\t 'S'- Square
  \t 'R'- Rectangle
  \t 'C'- Circle
  \t 'H'- Rhombus
  \t 'Q'- Quit
  """)

  if selection.upper() == 'Q':
    break

  area = calculate_area(selection)

  print(f"The area of the {get_shape_name(selection)} is {area}")
```

Comment: okay, I understand now, I was making it way more complicated than it needed to be. I was trying to place the whole code into a while statement instead of just one section.

Comment: Even better, move all functions outside of the loop and keep only the user input and the `calculate_area` function call. Also, use `upper()` for all inputs to accept both uppercase and lowercase letters. I updated the answer.

Comment: damn you made this look 10x better than I could have thought of. Thanks for the help and the learning experience.